# redirect http access.log to remote server in linux

Tags: linux, http, rsyslog

How do i redirect linux http access_log to a remote server via rsyslog configuraiton.? 
I could manage to send /var/log/secure message to remote server , tried the same way for access_log but it's not working. Did i miss anything ?

Answer (score 0):

if you known the logfile or identifier then you can have simple config, that can be seen in the default config like

```
auth*                @192.168.1.10:514    # For UDP syslog
auth*                @@192.168.1.10:514   # For TCP syslog
```

If these logs are not local to the system (i.e this is a centralized server) then you will need to filter and identify the logs that are coming in

for example if you message contains a unique string you can filter on that.

```
:msg, contains, "http access_log"      @1192.168.1.10:514 # UDP Syslog
```

Does that help?